# Python list display issue

Tags: python

Wasn't sure how to search for this so just decided to ask here.
How do I get the output list to display the number sets vertically?? I'm in 3.3

```
ROWS = 5
COLS = 2

def main():
    num1 = int(input('Type a whole number and press ENTER: '))
    values = [[10, 0],
              [13, 0],
              [36, 0],
              [74, 0],
              [22, 0]]

    for row in values:
        row[1] = row[0] + num1

    display(values)

def display(values):
    print(values)

    input('press enter to continue')

main()
```

Comment: What do you mean "display the numbers sets vertically"? Perhaps provide an example of the output you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through the elements of `values` (which are lists), and print a new-line on each iteration:

```
for row in values:
    print(row) # this will print a new-line after printing 'row'
```

Comment: Alternatively: `print(',\n'.join(str(row) for row in values))`